# Is the Jack Phantom different from the other Phantoms?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Depending on end result of Grissom Academy,

> It is reference that if you fail to save Grissom Academy, Jack is
>  captured and turned into a Phantom at Cerberus HQ. Does she have any
>  special stats?

I killed her quickly with my sniper rifle and didn't have time to see if anything was different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference seems to be that she has Jack-specific dialogue, like "[I will destroy you!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPJj8efNskM&feature=player_detailpage#t=34s)" Beyond that, she's no different than any other Phantom - she has the same barrier + health and the same weapons as the standard Phantom unit.